# Constructing a string out of several records with 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions, string-aggregation, postgresql-10

I have prepared a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3ff94/3) for my question -

In a word game written in Pl/pgSQL for PostgreSQL 10.2 player moves are stored in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE words_scores (
        mid     bigint  NOT NULL REFERENCES words_moves ON DELETE CASCADE,
        gid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_games ON DELETE CASCADE,
        uid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
        word    text    NOT NULL CHECK(word ~ '^[A-Z]{2,}$'),
        score   integer NOT NULL CHECK(score >= 0)
);
```

Here it is filled with some test data:

```
INSERT INTO words_scores (mid, gid, uid, word, score) VALUES
   (230, 209, 7, 'XY',  5),
   (230, 209, 7, 'XYZ', 15),
   (230, 209, 7, 'XAB', 13);
```

In a stored function I need to generate a string, which would contain all words played by a player in a certain move.

This is close to what I need and returns `XY, XYZ, XAB`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(word, ', ') FROM words_scores WHERE mid=230;
```

However I also need to have the score of each word in brackets, following each words as in:

```
XY (5), XYZ (15), XAB (13)
```

Is there maybe some clever use of [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html) possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FORMAT (as described in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)) to format your string before aggregation:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT('%s (%s)', word, score), ', ') FROM words_scores WHERE mid=230;
```

Here's the [updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3ff94/9).